# Need clarification on the status of my manuscript in ScholarOne

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, journal-workflow

I recently submitted a manuscript to a journal using the ScholarOne submission system. After the second round of review, the editor provided some minor language revisions, and all three reviewers had no further comments. However, after we made the revisions, the manuscript status changed to "Awaiting Reviewer Invitation." Does this mean that my manuscript needs to go through another round of review? Or it is just a brief status which actually means the paper is going to the chief editor?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice on this matter. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Manuscripts will go as many rounds of review as needed, until the reviewers (and ultimately, the editor) is happy with the manuscript status. I had papers published with 1 review, and papers published with 5. There is no way to tell.

When you review papers for such system, you are explicitly asked again if you would like (again) to be the reviewer for the second (nth) time.

The system is telling you that the invitation has been sent to the original (and perhaps new) reviewers and they are waiting for them to confirm.

In essence, there is no way to force the reviewers of the original submission to be a reviewer again, so they asked, again.

Comment: Thank you for you kind reply! I feel less anxious now. Thanks !! Hope things go well for you!